# Angular Karma test fails after adding Stripe

Tags: angular, stripe-payments, angular-universal, angular7

I've added Stripe Elements to an Angular 7 component, it works but I can't get the Karma/jasmine test to pass.

The error is:

```
ReferenceError: elements is not defined
```

As per this tutorial: https://alligator.io/angular/stripe-elements I added a typings.d.ts file with the lines:

```
declare var stripe: any;
declare var elements: any;
```

And then added the file to tsconfig.json like this:

```
"typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types", "src/typings.d.ts" ],
```

I tried some suggestions such as downloading the stripe.js file or including it in karma.conf.js like this but neither helped.

```
files: [ {pattern: 'https://js.stripe.com/v3', included: true}, './test/*.js' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This error was a red herring. After I resolved other Karma errors (including an error coming back from my API), this error went away.